# Use C# 7 tuples in a packaged MSBuild task

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget-package

The new C# 7 feature of tuples seems to require an additional NuGet package named System.ValueTuple. I've read something about this special package recently on a Microsoft blog but can't remember what it was. I believe that this additional type is already included in newer versions of the frameworks so it's a tricky package to install.

I'm using this in a NuGet package that contains an MSBuild task and targets .NET 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 1.6. The task can be used with Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, for .NET Framework as well as .NET Core/Standard projects. My package is built after [this tutorial](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/07/05/msbuild-task-in-nuget/).

So my .csproj file already contained this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="14.3.0" />
    <!-- later version with VS 2017: 15.1.1012 -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="14.3.0" />
    <!-- Marks all packages as 'local only' so they don't end up in the nuspec. -->
    <PackageReference Update="@(PackageReference)" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I needed to add another one:

```
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.4.0" />
```

But my MSBuild task didn't work anymore, complaining that the assembly "System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.2.0 …" or one of its dependencies could not be found. There is no trace whatsoever in my .nupkg file that this assembly would be required. So I changed my .csproj file to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="14.3.0">
        <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="14.3.0">
        <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>

    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But that didn't help either.

What is the suggested way to use the C# 7 tuples feature in this environment? Is that even possible at all? Has somebody in the C# design team thought about the complications that this nice handy feature is causing in the real world?

(edit) BTW, my package works in 'dotnet build' which uses the .NET Standard version of my MSBuild task dll. Visual Studio always uses the .NET Framework version of it, and that one doesn't work.

(edit) Here's the solution explorer view of my references to assemblies and NuGet packages:

[image: Project references]

Comment: Is there a System.ValueTuple deployed in the same directory as the task dll?

Comment: The directory is %userprofile%\.nuget\packages\%packageid%\%version%\tasks and there is just my own DLL, no other files.

Comment: you'll need to include the file. Adding a package reference does not include the referenced dll automatically into that folder, but it needs to be there for msbuild/.net framework to find.

Comment: @MartinUllrich I've added a screenshot of the references. I don't know how the NuGet section of it is handled. Is this enough? What more can I do?

Comment: Even when I uninstall the System.ValueTuple NuGet package entirely and copy in the DLL and add the reference the old way, that DLL will never be copied along with the MSBuild task DLL. It seems the compiler is just ignoring this reference. Is that a bug in MSBuild/Visual Studio?

Comment: No, you'd have to do some msbuild tricks to include it or use a manual nuspec file for packing the final layout.. in the meantime you could try if this is the right way by copying the net* dll from the valuetuple nuget package to the location that the task is used from (e.g. global nuget cache) to see if this would fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to help in my MSBuild custom task project .csproj file.

I extracted the System.ValueTuple.dll file from its NuGet package and included it in my source code. It's a small file (80 kB) so I have no issue with that. It won't be as simple to update this file, but I'm not going to do that anyway if it works now.

I can now use my MSBuild task package with .NET Core projects in Visual Studio 2017 and the .NET Core SDK 2.0 (`dotnet build`) as well as with .NET Framework projects in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="build\*" PackagePath="build\" />
    <Content Include="buildMultiTargeting\*" PackagePath="buildMultiTargeting\" />
    <!-- C# 7 tuples requires System.ValueTuple, but adding the NuGet package won't copy the DLL to
    the output directory, where it is needed for MSBuild to find it for this tasks DLL. So we just
    revert to the plain old manual references and use the .NETStandard1.0 build of that DLL. It
    still needs to be copied manually because the compiler ignores it. But with this method, at
    least we know where to copy it from. -->
    <Content Include="lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll" PackagePath="tasks\net46\" />
    <Content Include="lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll" PackagePath="tasks\netstandard1.6\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework" Version="14.3.0" />
    <!-- later version with VS 2017: 15.1.1012 -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core" Version="14.3.0" />
    <!-- Marks all packages as 'local only' so they don't end up in the nuspec. -->
    <PackageReference Update="@(PackageReference)" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple">
        <HintPath>lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```